# Deploy war files in hybris tomcat

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to deploy a war file in Hybris tomcat folder. I placed it on **\bin\platform\tomcat\webapps** path and started the server. Eventually, a folder should be generated for this war file. but it is NOT GENERATED.
Any help.

Answer (score 1):

Once your server has started, check the directory, `hybris⁩ ▸ ⁨bin⁩ ▸ ⁨platform⁩ ▸ ⁨tomcat⁩ ▸ ⁨work⁩ ▸ ⁨Catalina⁩ ▸ ⁨localhost⁩` and there you will find your war file exploded into a folder.

The content of the exploded folder depends on how you have packaged your war e.g. as shown in the screenshot below, the source code hasn't been selected to be exported to the war file and therefore in the exploded folder, you will find only `WEB-INF` and its sub-directories.

[image]

Comment: Yes, its there. Compared to I deployed the war file in standalone Tomcat, folders/files generated in Hybris Tomcat are different. Why so ?

Comment: Great! I've posted an update to answer your question from the comment.

Comment: One more question @arvind-kumar-avinash, do we need to set the localextension.xml too for deploying the war file like <webapp contextroot="webchat" path="${HYBRIS_CONFIG_DIR}/path/webchat.war"/> . Take for example webchat.war is the war to be deployed.

Comment: Your answer is useful when doing war file deployment in standalone tomcat. That too when placing the war file in bin\platform\resources\tomcat-7.0.82\webapps path.

Comment: @PriyaS - It's a bad idea to accept an answer first and then un-accept it after some days when you find a better answer. Stackoverflow is full of such instances that people find a better answer after some days and they add the same but they do it without un-accepting the originally accepted answer. Un-accepting an answer is justified only in cases where a wrong answer was accepted in lack of knowledge; otherwise, SO community considers it a rude behaviour. This is just FYI so that you do not repeat it in the future.

Comment: I felt this answer is useful but not correct, so I un-accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got the answer. Posting it so that others can use it.
Steps to deploy war file in Hybris embedded tomcat server and the expanded folder path:

1. Add webapp contextroot="Address" path="${HYBRIS_CONFIG_DIR}/addressABC/test.war"/> in
   localextension.xml at the end but before last .
2. Add the war(Example test.war) file in the above path.
3. Do ant all, and start the server.
4. **WAR file will get expanded to** -> bin/custom/Address folder.